# React Native (Expo Managed) epub Reader without Web View

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, epub

I need an epub reader for React Native (Expo Managed) which is pure and not displaying a web view. Because I have to apply some custom styling like choices of fonts, colors, themes etc.

One I can find is ejecting out of expo which is not recommended for me. If you guys can guide me on how to write my own(unzipping epub and then making its HTML display view "react-native-render-html") if nothing is available.

"Epub.js React Native Components" needs to eject from Expo which I don't want to.

One other thing is, I can make a nodejs service which can return me HTML and Image base64 string. But that would be the worst case scenario.

Thanks